# how to simulate key press in Android with AccessibilityService

Tags: android, keyboard, accessibilityservice

I am writing an accessibility service. I've been trying to do some auto search on an app. I uses the accessibilityservice action_paste to fill in the EditText. Then I need to simulate the key press on the soft keyboard. But I didn't find out how to. Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score -3):

You could try `Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent)`
There are also functions in [Instrumentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html) But those are mostly for testing.

Comment: AccessibilityNodeInfo node = getRootInActiveWindow();

Comment: But that is not my app. I need to do using APIs such as AccessibilityService. But I can't get the soft keyboard view by searching the root node in the currently active window through AccessibilityService API.

Comment: I am very grateful that you can answer my question. Maybe I don't need to access the keyboard. I just want to press the "enter" button on the soft keyboard programmatically. Do you know how to? Do you think something like 'Programmatically Injecting Events on Android' can help?

Comment: Thanks, I have solved my problem by using adb shell code.

Comment: Can you explain that how you solve that problem @Anny because same problem currently i am facing now

Comment: @anny can you please explain how did you solve this problem