# Unable to input "enter" key event from within my app android

Tags: android, keyevent, accessibilityservice, adb

I want to input "enter" key event programmatically from within my app.

I have tried it using abd shell command as well as using AccessibilityService, but found no luck in it.

[Similar question was asked here as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285587/how-to-simulate-key-press-in-android-with-accessibilityservice/)

Below is my code which I used to execute adb shell command :

```
try {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

    Process p = runtime.exec("input keyevent 66");

    BufferedReader standardIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader errorIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    String output = "";
    String line;
    while ((line = standardIn.readLine()) != null) {
        output += line + "\n";
    }
    while ((line = errorIn.readLine()) != null) {
        output += line + "\n";
    }

    Log.d("output", "" + output);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am getting the following output :

```
sh: resetreason: can't execute: Permission denied
```

Someone please help me out.

If anyone knows how to achieve it using AccessibilityService as well, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Add this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />` permission & Try again .

Comment: Added the above permission, but still throwing same output error.

Comment: I think the above permission and the above code will only work on rooted devices.